# Is the promise of "works" in John 14:12 only for the apostles or for Christians in all ages?

Tags: john, jesus, referent-identification, miracle, continuationism

John 14:8-14 (NIV) says:

> ⁸Philip said, “Lord, show us the Father and that will be enough for us.”  ⁹Jesus answered: “Don’t you know me, Philip, even after I have been among you such a long time? Anyone who has seen me has seen the Father. How can you say, ‘Show us the Father’? ¹⁰Don’t you believe that I am in the Father, and that the Father is in me? The words I say to you I do not speak on my own authority. Rather, it is the Father, living in me, who is doing his work. ¹¹**Believe me when I say that I am in the Father and the Father is in me; or at least believe on the evidence of the works themselves. ¹²Very truly I tell you, whoever believes in me will do the works I have been doing, and they will do even greater things than these, because I am going to the Father**. ¹³And I will do whatever you ask in my name, so that the Father may be glorified in the Son. ¹⁴You may ask me for anything in my name, and I will do it.

Was the promise in verse 12 ***"whoever believes in me will do the works I have been doing, and they will do even greater things than these"*** only for the apostles or for Christians in all ages?

In regards to what I personally understand by **'works'**, in verse 11 Jesus gives us insight into what he means:

> ¹¹ Believe me when I say that I am in the Father and the Father is in me; **or at least believe on the evidence of the works themselves**.

Moreover, in Luke 7:20-23 (NIV) Jesus is even more explicit:

> ²⁰When the men came to Jesus, they said, “John the Baptist sent us to you to ask, ‘Are you the one who is to come, or should we expect someone else?’” ²¹At that very time Jesus cured many who had diseases, sicknesses and evil spirits, and gave sight to many who were blind. ²²So he replied to the messengers, **“Go back and report to John what you have seen and heard: The blind receive sight, the lame walk, those who have leprosy are cleansed, the deaf hear, the dead are raised, and the good news is proclaimed to the poor**. ²³Blessed is anyone who does not stumble on account of me.”

But feel free to justify a different interpretation of 'works' if you don't agree with this.

Comment: believers in Christ for all ages, of course! He addresses the 12, not Paul, but does not Paul do those things? Does not Barnabas? He speaks in the given quotation about all who would believe in Him, so do not the Apostles preach that people may believe in Jesus? Yes. And so it is inclusive to all who will believe. self evident things!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is given in the same verse, John 14:12 - the key is provided by the Greek phrase as to who will do the works of Jesus and even great things:

> ὁ πιστεύων εἰς ἐμὲ = the one believing in me

Thus, as I understand it, anyone who believe in Jesus will do the same works as Jesus and even greater works.  To make this clearer, many version translate thus:

- NIV: whoever believes in me
- NLT: anyone who believes in me
- ESV: whoever believes in me
- NET: the person who believes in me
- GWT: Those who believe in me

Thus, anyone who believes in Jesus is promised these great things!